# Is a function legitimate?

Tags: functions

Let $S$ be the set of nonnegative rational numbers, that is, $S = \{m/n \mid m, n \ \mathrm{are\ nonnegative\ integers}, n \neq 0 \}$, and let $T$ be the set of all integers.
(a) Does $f: S \to T$ defined by $f(m) = 2^m 3^n$ define a legitimate function
from $S$ to $T$?

a) What does it mean for a function to be legitimate? Is f a legitimate function?
b) If not, how could you modify the definition of f so as to get a legitimate function?

Comment: Notice $.75 = \frac 34 = \frac 68$.  So what is $f(.75)$?  Is is $2^3*3^4$ or is it $2^6*2^8$?

Answer (score 2):

A function $f:S\to T$ needs to have a unique value for every element of $S$. So the question you need to answer is: If $f(m,n) \neq f(m',n')$, do $(m,n)$ and $(m',n')$ necessarily correspond to distinct elements of $S$?

If not, can you think of how to solve this?

Legitimate is not a technical term I have come across, usually people say "well-defined".

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following proof. Is it correct ?

a) To be a legitimate function *f : S $\to$ T* , the following condition must be satistfied:
 For every *s $\in$ S*, there is a unique t $\in$ T, such that *f(s) = t.*
Let *m=6,n=8,m'=3,n'=4.* Then m/n = m'/n'. But *f(6/8)* $\neq$ *f(3/4)*, therefore same element from S maps to two different t from T. Hence this is not a legitimate(well-defined) function.

b) Since they only ask as to modify the definition of *f* so that the function is well-defined, I assumed that I can set *f* whatever value I want.
***f(m/n) = m/n***
This is well-defined function.

Comment: a) is correct, as is b). However, I suspect what the question wants you to do is define $f$ as $f(m/n)=2^m3^n$ where $m$ and $n$ are *coprime*. So this means $f(6/8) = f(3 / 4) = 2^33^4$.